# SQL query to Find highest value in table and sum the corresponding value

Tags: sql

I would like to group Highest values in month column group by year and Sum the value column

| value | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2019 | 10 |
| 1 | 2019 | 11 |
| 5 | 2019 | 11 |
| 1 | 2019 | 11 |
| 1 | 2019 | 12 |
| 8 | 2019 | 12 |
| 1 | 2019 | 12 |
| 1 | 2020 | 1 |
| 10 | 2020 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2 |
| 11 | 2021 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021 | 3 |

In above table I would like to extract highest value of month group by year
in year 2019 highest month is 12 so there are 3 rows and sum of value column will be 10

The output should be

| value | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2019 | 12 |
| 11 | 2020 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021 | 3 |

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? Please [edit] your post and remove the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

supposing that the table is called "example_table" you can use the following query:

```
select sum(example_table.value), example_table.year, example_table.month
from example_table
join (
    select year, max(month) "month"
    from example_table
    group by year
) sub on example_table.year = sub.year and example_table.month = sub.month
group by example_table.year, example_table.month
order by example_table.year
```